# Moment of Inertia

Tags: dynamics

[image: diagram]
To calculate the moment of inertia at o, I tried to apply (1/3mq^2) but I am not sure if it is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the question assumes the rod to be of negligible mass.

Then the rotational moment of inertia is just $I=mq^2 $

You may have confused the moment of inertia of a rod of mass m with length q.